# Get Static Image url access count in Appengine

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

My appliaction need to save the particular static image accessed count in datastore.

Here is the Current Code:

`Image URL: http://my_app.appspot.com/static_image`

```
class Image_Display(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...........
        // Increment the count & save it in datastore

        self.redirect("/images/static.gif")            

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/static_image', Image_Display)], debug=False)
```

Instead of `self.redirect("/images/static.gif")`, Is the better way to do this ?

In this case, Always have 2 request for each image request.

```
"GET /static_image HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /images/static.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1453
```

Comment: I'm guessing when accessed from one particular link because if they are accessed directly you have to the `static.gif` then your handler is being skipped.. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a redirect you use two requests. You can also read the image from the static project path in a single request:

```
class Image_Display(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        ...........
        // Increment the count & save it in datastore

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'images', 'static.gif')
        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type('static.gif')[0]
        self.response.write(file(path, 'rb').read())
```